# keeping track of vector pair indices upon sorting

Tags: c++, stl

Similar things have been asked before but I am having trouble applying the concept. I would like to to keep track of the indices of the pairs in my vector of pairs then, once sorted, std::cout the input order.

e.g.

```
cin >> 5 6 1 5 1 2 1 2 3 5
cout << 1 2 1 2 1 5 3 5 5 6
cout >> 3 4 2 5 1  //and this is where I am having trouble.
```

I was thinking of converting to triples, where one of the elements is the index but I couldn't get that to conform to my needs.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

bool compare(const pair<int,int>&A, const pair<int,int>&B);

int main()
{
    vector<pair<int,int>> v;
    pair<int,int> tok;
    while(cin >> tok.first>>tok.second){v.push_back(tok);}

    sort(v.begin(),v.end(), compare);
    for(int i = (signed int)v.size()-1; i >= 0 ; i--)
    {
        cout << v.at(i).first << " ";
        cout << v.at(i).second << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}

bool compare(const pair<int,int>&A, const pair<int,int>&B)
{
    return A.first > B.first;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it. Long time since I did someone's homework for them ;-)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;


const string input_data = "5 6 1 5 1 2 1 2 3 5";

typedef pair<int, int> integer_pair;
typedef pair<int, integer_pair> integer_pair_with_input_order;

bool less_by_integer_pair(const integer_pair_with_input_order& l,
                             const integer_pair_with_input_order& r)
{
    return l.second < r.second;
}

int main()
{
    // note - I did this to avoid having to type numbers in.
    std::istringstream simulate_cin(input_data);

    vector<integer_pair_with_input_order> v;
    integer_pair tok;
    int input_order = 0;
    while(simulate_cin >> tok.first >> tok.second) {
        v.push_back(make_pair(++input_order, tok));
    }

    sort(v.begin(),v.end(), less_by_integer_pair);

    for (int i = 0 ; i < v.size() ; ++i)
    {
        const integer_pair_with_input_order& elem = v[i];
        cout << "input order : " << elem.first
        << " { " << elem.second.first
        << ", " << elem.second.second << " }\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I should have prefaced it by indicating that this is part of an assignment.